# create a jQuery table using <tr> and <td> tags

Tags: jquery

I wanna create a 6x7 table, I wrote the code below to create 7 rows, can someone tells me how to add 6 columns to put 6  into each ?

```
for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    $("<tr></tr>").appendTo('table');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to create dynamic table like this.

Two for loop will be used.Outer `for` loop for the Rows and inner `for` loop for the columns.

```js
$('#dynamictable').append('<table>');
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var str = "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        str += "<td style='background:#ccc;'>cell</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
    table.append(str);
}
$('#dynamictable').append('</table>');
```

```css
table {
    background:#CCC;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
table td {
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dynamictable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this :

```
var nbRows = 7;
var nbColumns = 6;
for (i = 0; i < nbRows; i++) {
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    for(j=0; j<nbColumns;j++){
        tr.append("<td></td>");
    }
    tr.appendTo('table');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(var i=0; i<7; i++)
        {   
            $("table").append("<tr></tr>");


        }
        for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
        { 
         $("table tr").append("<td>"+i+"</td>");
         }
```

try it.